# What is the expected behavior if UAC is off for standard windows user?

Tags: uac

If the UAC level is set to Never and a Standard Windows user runs up an app that requests for elevated admin privileges, what would be the expected behavior, should the app continue to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the microsoft documentation:

The slider will never turn UAC completely off. If you set it to Never notify, it will:

- Keep the UAC service running.
- Cause all elevation request initiated by administrators to be auto-approved without showing a UAC prompt.
- Automatically deny all elevation requests for standard users.

This means that any application requiring admin privileges won't run, as the user has no admin privileges.